# Email Change Confirmation module -- Avoid confirmation email from user_login hook

Tags: emails

I'm using the "Email Change Confirmation" (email_confirm) module with Drupal 7. It works well. However, I also have a user_login hook that sets certain users' email addresses, thus:

```
    user_save($user, ['mail' => '<new address>']);
```

In this instance, I want the change to take effect immediately, without the need for confirmation (via email or otherwise). The module already provides a configuration option to override sending a confirmation email when the address is changed via the interface by users with specified roles. I want it to behave like that when I change it via the login hook. Is there a way to override sending an email in this case?

Answer (score 1):

After looking at the email_confirm code, I came up with a simple solution. A confirmation message isn't sent if an email address is changed to or from empty, so:

```
  user_save($user, ['mail' => '']);
  user_save($user, ['mail' => '<new address>']);
```

does the trick.